# How submit information from several forms in powerapps

Tags: powerapps

I Create a simple app in PowerApps with several screens but the information, do not upload to the datasource.

[image]
This picture shows the `Screen1`, just one button, and `OnSelect` try to set the `Form1` and `Form2` to `NewForm`, and the Transition, Display mode just the classic validation.

[image]
Second picture, shows the `Screen2` with the `Form1`. This form has 2 textboxes connected to the datasource. The Back and the `Next` button. Nothing special

[image]
Third picture, and pretty the same in `Screen2`.

[image]
And the final screen with just a button, but with the wrong results.

Everything is loaded into a Sharepoint List.

My question:

I want a the user goes throw the screens answering the questions, and in the final screen with one button, send all the information to the datasource. But only the last form (Form2) is loaded, and do not know why o how to solve this.

Comment: Have a look at Matthew Devaney's post on the same: [Absolute Best Way To Make Multiple Page Forms In Power Apps](https://www.matthewdevaney.com/absolute-best-way-to-make-multiple-page-forms-in-power-apps/)